# i got MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php

Tags: php, laravel

i got error message `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` in `RouteCollection.php`

here is service.blade.php

```
<form ACTION="{{ url('backend/client/updateservice' ) }}" METHOD="POST" id="form1" name="form1" >
   <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">     
</form>
```

here is route.php

```
Route::get('backend/client/editservice','Backend\ClientController@editservice');
Route::post('backend/client/updateservice','Backend\ClientController@updateservice');
```

here is ClientController.php

```
public function editservice()
{
  $client = Client::where('ClientID','1') -> get() -> first();
  return view('backend/client.service',compact('client'));
}

public function updateservice()
{
  $clientUpdate = Input::all();
  $client = Client::where('ClientID','1') -> get() -> first();
  $client ->update($clientUpdate);
  return redirect('backend/client/service');
}
```

Comment: try changing method names to getEditservice and postUpdateservice and in routes also.

Comment: kindly check the full error where the form have submitted then check the method of that URL in route.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to` instead of `url`

```
<form ACTION="{{ URL::to('backend/client/updateservice') }}" METHOD="POST" id="form1" name="form1" >
```

Or

```
Route::post('backend/client/updateservice',array('uses'=>'Backend\ClientController@updateservice','as'=>'updataService'));
```

Use `route()` helper function for that:

```
<form ACTION="{{ URL::route('updataService') }}" METHOD="POST" id="form1" name="form1" >
```

Comment: The second one is better, you can define a name for your route

Comment: Yes I am sure please try that

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your `redirect` option of `updateservice` method. Change `updateservice` method to this

```
public function updateservice()
{
  $clientUpdate = Input::all();
  $client = Client::where('ClientID','1') -> get() -> first();
  $client ->update($clientUpdate);
  return redirect('backend/client/editservice');
}
```

Because when it redirect it could not find redirected route

Comment: No, it can't be, it is not going inside method body, that exception occurs only when it don't find any method